# Braintree's Java API querying on Auth amount but returning settled amount

Tags: java, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I am using Braintree's Java API to query the transactions for searching. When I do this -

```
TransactionSearchRequest request = new TransactionSearchRequest()
  .amount().between(new BigDecimal("100.00"), new BigDecimal("200.00"));
```

I get back a list of Transactions some of whose value is less than 100 when I do transanction.getAmount(). On investigating further, it seems these transactions were authorized for a larger amount but the eventually settled amount was lesser. How do I resolve this? It seems to query only on Auth amount. And the returned object only seems to have settled amount.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact 
[support](https://www.braintreepayments.com/contact).</sub>

If you authorize a transaction for a certain amount and submit less for settlement, it is not currently possible to run a [transaction search](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/search) based on the amount that was submitted for settlement. Our API will use the authorized amount when returning results. A workaround for this is to run a Transaction Search using the authorized amount or based on other information besides the amount, such as the [customer information](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/search/ruby#searching-on-customer-details) or the [payment method token](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/search/ruby#vault-associations).